# read implementation of Fuse in python not returning as expected, cat: <mountpoint>: bad address

Tags: python, git, filesystems, fuse

I am trying to fetch data from some repository and am trying to display file contents of any file for instance with `cat <filename>` inside a repository directory.

```
def read(self, path, size, offset, fh=None):
    file_content = ''
    path_ele = path.split('/')
    print('***[read]')
    print(path)
    if path.endswith('/') or path[1] == '.':
        print('ok')
        return file_content
    else:
        path = path.split('/')
        repo_name = path[-2]
        file_name = path[-1]
        print(repo_name, file_name)
        for item in self.user.get_user().get_repos():
            if item.name == repo_name:
                files = item.get_dir_contents('/')
                for file_ in files:
                    if file_name == file_.name:
                        file_content = item.get_file_contents(file_name).decoded_content
                        print(len(file_content.decode('utf-8')))
                        print(type(file_content.decode('utf-8')))
                        return file_content
```

When I do `cat` on a file in a repository directory it gives me an error caused by the following line

```
assert retsize <= size, 'actual amount read %d greater than expected %d' % (retsize, size)
```

in `fusepy`s read function [link](https://github.com/terencehonles/fusepy/blob/master/fuse.py#L589).

Answer (score 1):

You do not respect all parameters of `read`, i.e. `size` and `offset`. Certain programs or commands read only chunks of files at a time. This means that they expect to be able to read x bytes (`size`) starting at position y bytes (`offset`). So your primary mistake in your code snipped is that you just return the entire file for every read operation.

A fix could start with something trivial like returning `file_content[offset:(offset+size)]`. When I say "start", you have to keep in mind that you must also raise proper errors if the `offset` or `size` (for the given `offset`) passed into your `read` function are out of bounds.